# Packer credentials issue error "NoCredentialProviders"?

Tags: amazon-web-services, packer

I'm trying to run a Packer template to build a basic AWS EBS based instance. I keep getting the following error however.

```
==> amazon-ebs: Error querying AMI: NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated. 
==> amazon-ebs:         For verbose messaging see aws.Config.CredentialsChainVerboseErrors
Build 'amazon-ebs' errored: Error querying AMI: NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated. 
        For verbose messaging see aws.Config.CredentialsChainVerboseErrors
```

I've got my credentials pulling from environment variables like this in the template.

```
{
  "type": "amazon-ebs",
  "access_key": "{{user `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`}}",
  "secret_key": "{{user `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`}}",
  "region": "us-east-1",
  "source_ami": "ami-fce3c696",
  "instance_type": "t2.micro",
  "ssh_username": "broodadmin",
  "ami_name": "broodbox"
}
```

I pulled the key and secret from AWS, and have setup the permissions for the group per instructions in the docs [here](https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/amazon.html). I've also insured the user is in the group that has all of these permissions set.

Seen this?

This is more of the template with the other google compute and variables in the template listed...

```
{
  "variables": {
    "account_json": "../../../secrets/account.json",
    "instance_name": "broodbox",
    "image_name": "broodbox"
  },
  "builders": [
    {
      "type": "googlecompute",
      "account_file": "{{user `account_json`}}",
      "project_id": "that-big-universe",
      "source_image": "debian-8-jessie-v20160923",
      "zone": "us-west1-a",
      "instance_name": "{{user `instance_name`}}",
      "image_name": "{{user `image_name`}}",
      "image_description": "Node.js Server.",
      "communicator": "ssh",
      "ssh_username": "broodadmin"
    },
    {
      "type": "amazon-ebs",
      "access_key": "{{user `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`}}",
      "secret_key": "{{user `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`}}",
      "region": "us-east-1",
      "source_ami": "ami-fce3c696",
      "instance_type": "t2.micro",
      "ssh_username": "broodadmin",
      "ami_name": "broodbox"
    }
  ],
  "provisioners": [
```

The full template is here https://github.com/Adron/multi-cloud/blob/master/ecosystem/packer/nodejs_server.json

The repo is a mult-cloud repo I'm working on https://github.com/Adron/multi-cloud

Comment: Please supply your full template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a go at running the template, and the only way I could get it to return that error was if the environment variables didn't exist. Once i created them, I got a different error:

`==> amazon-ebs: Error launching source instance: VPCResourceNotSpecified: The specified instance type can only be used in a VPC. A subnet ID or network interface ID is required to carry out the request.`

So, if you create the variables `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`, you should be fine. (I seem to recall that I've occasionally seen the variables called `AWS_ACCESS_KEY` and `AWS_SECRET_KEY` which has tripped me up in the past.)

Comment: Ah, that fixed the issue. For some reason it just wasn't picking up the environment variables even when they were set. I went with the ~/.aws/credentials method and it picked them up there once I removed them from the environment variables.  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 3):

Doing a bit of rubber ducking here. But you haven't added the user variables `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`. You need to add these lines to you `variables` section:

```
"AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID": "{{env `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`}}",
"AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY": "{{env `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`}}"
```

See docs about [environment-variables](https://www.packer.io/docs/templates/user-variables.html#environment-variables) for more information.

But what you probably want to do is to just delete these two lines from your `amazon-ebs` builder section:

```
"access_key": "{{user `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`}}",
"secret_key": "{{user `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`}}",
```

Since then Packer will read them from the default environment variables (which you anyway are using). See [Packer Documentation - AWS credentials](https://www.packer.io/docs/builders/amazon.html#specifying-amazon-credentials).

Comment: Ah, wiped em' out and went with the ~/.aws/credentials file and that seems to have em' getting picked up now. Except now I get the issue Matt Richardson is pointing out above.

Comment: You need to specify `vpc_id` and `subnet_id` too.

Comment: Yeah, realized that after fiddling with it a bit longer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe `access_key` and `secret_key` are not as required as the docs make them out to be. I would remove those properties from the builder and — as long as the `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` environment variables are exported — the builder should pick them up. It will also use the default credential lookup strategy used by the AWS Go SDK to find `~/.aws/credentials`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

My decision for Linux:

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="XXX"

export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="XXX"
```

and remove from config

```
"access_key": "{{user `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`}}",

"secret_key": "{{user `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`}}",
```